# How to pass arguments to javaFx deployed application

Tags: deployment, javafx

I have a Java application, I am using JavaFx deployment steps + ant to build this application. I have two kinds of this applications. One is user interface and other is command line version. If I provide arguments at command prompt then it run as command line application. 
For eg -
C:\CmdApp.exe -name:myname -class:myClass

Trying this on exe created with JavaFx nothing is shown at command prompt. Is there other way to read command line arguments ?

Note : My application is created in Java not in JavaFX
I have provided argumnets in my build.xml in deployment steps as -

```
   <fx:application name="${commandlineapp.title}" mainClass="${main.class} toolkit=swing">
                    <fx:argument>Arg1</fx:argument>
                    <fx:argument>Arg2</fx:argument>
                    <fx:argument>Arg3</fx:argument>
                    <fx:argument>Arg4</fx:argument>
                    <fx:argument>Arg5</fx:argument>    </fx:application>
```

Please let me know how to pass command line argument to run my command line application using JavaFx deplyment?

Thanks